# Elementary tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

I need to determine whether the following function is tensor on $\Bbb R^4$ and express it in terms of elementary tensors. Can someone please help me with it? I do not know what elementary tensor means either. 
$$f(x,y)=3x_1y_2+5x_2 x_3$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm, $\color{Blue}{x_1},\color{Blue}{x_2},\color{Blue}{x_3},\color{Green}{y_2}$: sure your variables are right? I assume you're checking if this is a bilinear map $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ (in which case elementary tensors I believe correspond to products of linear functionals).

Comment: I am sure the variables are right. That's whats there. And it is written that I need to determine if it is a tensor on $\Bbb R^4$. I am using Munkres's analysis.

Comment: If this is in a textbook can you give the page #?

Comment: Sure. page 226 problem 4 @anon

Comment: Ah, it means $\Bbb R^4\times\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R$. Okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $ f: \mathbb{R}^{4} \times \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R} $, as mentioned by anon.

Now, a tensor can be defined as a multi-linear mapping. Hence, if $ f $ were a tensor, it would have to satisfy
$$
\forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{4}, ~ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \quad
f(\lambda \cdot \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \lambda \cdot f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
\quad \text{and} \quad
f(\mathbf{x},\lambda \cdot \mathbf{y}) = \lambda \cdot f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}).
$$
However, by choosing $ \mathbf{x} = (0,1,1,0) $, $ \mathbf{y} = (0,0,0,0) $ and $ \lambda = 2 $, we see that
\begin{align}
    f(\lambda \cdot \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
& = 3 (\lambda x_{1}) y_{2} + 5 (\lambda x_{2}) (\lambda x_{3}) \\
& = 20; \\
    \lambda \cdot f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
& = \lambda (3 x_{1} y_{2} + 5 x_{2} x_{3}) \\
& = 10.
\end{align}
Therefore, $ f $ is *not* a tensor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does elementary tensor means tho? Can you talk about that a bit?

Comment: @MarionCrane: Hi Marion. An elementary tensor is defined as a **multi-linear mapping** $ g: \mathbb{R}^{4} \times \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R} $ that satisfies
$$
\forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{4}: \quad
  g(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})
= \phi(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \psi(\mathbf{y}),
$$
where $ \phi $ and $ \psi $ are both linear functionals on $ \mathbb{R}^{4} $. We then write $ g = \phi \otimes \psi $. As $ f $ has been shown to be *not* a tensor, it cannot be a sum of elementary tensors.